# Java StringBuilder character appending returns unwanted number

Tags: java, unicode, append, stringbuilder, bluej

I am very sorry if this is a basic question which has been answered before (I tried looking but I did not find anything)

I am trying to write the following Java method:

```
 String winningCard(String trick, char trump) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char suit;
    char rank;
    for(int i = 1;   i < trick.length(); i+=2) {
        if(trick.charAt(i) == trump) {
            suit = trick.charAt(i);
            rank = trick.charAt(i-1);
            sb.append(rank + suit); //issue here, returns a weird number
            break;
        }
    }
    String result = sb.toString();
    return result;
}
```

When called with these arguments "8s7hQd", 'h' for example, it is supposed to return "7h".

If I change the StringBuilder to only append either the suit or the rank, it does it just fine, but if I put it the way it is above it returns "159" which I believe has something to do with the unicode encoding.

I'd very much appreciate if a kind sould could tell me what I am missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `sb.append(rank); sb.append(suit);` instead of the one line `sb.append(rank + suit);`?

Comment: Wow, that did it! Thank you deHaar, you've solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

`suit` and `rank` are basically numbers. The + is adding these numbers and appending it.

If you place a `""` between, the chars will be appended as you intend, because it forces the compiler to use the + with a String.

```
sb.append(rank + "" + suit);
```

Comment: You could simply put `""` between them (or before them); it doesn't look like OP intended a space.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I thought I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

```
append(rank).append(suit);
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

`+` is a tricksy thing, because it means different things in different contexts.

- If at least one of the operands is a `String`, it acts as the *string concatenation* operator.
- If both of the operands are numbers, or convertible to numbers via unboxing, then it acts as the *numeric addition* operator.

You are giving it two `char`s: these are numbers, so numeric addition occurs.

Before adding the two chars, they are widened to `int`; the result is an `int` too. And it is this `int` that you are appending to the string builder, hence the "unwanted" number.

So, either avoid using the addition operator at all (best):

```
sb.append(rank).append(suit);
```

Or make sure you are using the string concatenation operator:

```
sb.append("" + rank + suit);
// Left-associative, so evaluated as
// ("" + rank) + suit

sb.append(String.valueOf(rank) + suit);
// Etc.
```

---

But actually, you don't need to do either: just append the substring:

```
sb.append(trick, i-1, i+1);
```

This extracts a portion of the `trick` string, as `trick.substring(i-1, i+1)` would, but does it without creating a new string.

And you don't need a loop

Answer (score 0):

You can say directly that those chars should be interpreted as String by

```
sb.append(String.valueOf(rank) + String.valueOf(suit))
```